# How to calculate pressure using flow rate and pipe guage

Tags: pressure

On my farm I have a high pressure spring coming from the ground.it exits the ground from a 1 & 3/4" pipe.the water flows at a constant rate of 1 gallon per second (60 GPM.) Is it possible to approximately calculate the head or psi from these figures. I would like to use this spring to power a small water turbine but am unable to calculate head as the water comes upwards under pressure and if psi is calculated, how can that be converted to a 'metres head' number which most turbines are rated in. Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relation between water flow and pressure](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28093/)

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between flow rate and pressure is given by the [Darcy-Weisbach equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation). The problem is that using it requires you to know the geometry of the pipe underground. I suspect you'll struggle to do an accurate calculation. Your best option is probably to try and borrow a pressure gauge.